# The question migration notice should be hidden after a certain time threshold

Tags: feature-request, migration

I frequently come across posts as old as 2016 or earlier that have big yellow migration notice boxes stuck at their bottom.

> migrated from xyz.stackexchange.com Feb 4 '16 at 20:33
>
> This question came from our P, Q, and R site for A, B and C.

These migration notices help out the people *at the time* the question was migrated, but I believe they lose their value after a few days (say one week). For example, I don't think that if I'm searching for the [decomposition of calcium carbonate](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44739/why-does-calcium-carbonate-decompose-in-sulphuric-acid) in 2018, before showing me the answers, I first must be told that the post was migrated two years earlier...

Of course, I can always ignore it and continue on reading the answers ... but that's not my point. My point is that the migration notice has served its purpose after a certain time threshold, and should be removed after that.

I have seen "Bumped by Community Users" notices go away within a day or two after they've served their purpose. Then what is the rationale behind retaining post migration notices for *years*? Why not remove them after a certain time threshold?

(obvious clarification: the associated migration event should still be retained within the post's timeline)